# submaximal space

Tags: general-topology

- A space X is said to be submaximal if every dense set of X is open in X (i.e., every preopen set of X is open in X. ‎‎A subset ‎‎$‎S‎$‎ of ‎$‎(X, ‎\tau)‎$‎ is said to ‎be‎ ‎"preopen" if ‎$‎S ‎\subset‎ \text{int}(\text{cl}(S)‎$‎‎.
- A space X is said to be extremally disconnected (in brief , E.D.,) space if Cl(G) is open set for each open set G of X.
- Is every submaximal space, extremally disconnected? If not, can you tell me a counterexample?

Comment: A convergent sequence is another counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{p\}\cup(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)$, where $p$ is some point not in $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. Points of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ are isolated, and the sets

$$B_n=\{p\}\cup\{\langle k,\ell\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:k\ge n\}$$

form a local base at $p$. The only dense sets in $X$ are $X$ and $X\setminus\{p\}$, both of which are open, so $X$ is submaximal.

Let $G=\Bbb N\times\{0\}$. Then $G$ is open, but $\operatorname{cl}G=G\cup\{p\}$ is not open, so $X$ is not extremally disconnected.